# Uri Query SMS to get todays sent SMS count

Tags: java, android, sms

I am sending `SMS` from `code` & also updating the `Systems` SMS `Sent` messages; with :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1)
{
    int subscriptionId = SmsManager.getDefaultSmsSubscriptionId();
    SmsManager MySmsManager = SmsManager.getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId(subscriptionId);
    ArrayList<String> msgArray = MySmsManager.divideMessage(DefaultMsgTemplate);
    MySmsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(SendSMSTo, null,msgArray, null, null);
    CurrentSmsParts = msgArray.size();

    Log.d("SMS DETAILS : ", "\nFOUND LOLLIPOP MR1 OR ABOVE...");
    Log.d("SMS DETAILS : ", "\nDETECTED DEFAULT SMS SIM..."+subscriptionId);
    Log.d("SMS DETAILS : ", "\nSENT MSG USING SIM..."+subscriptionId);
}
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1)
{
    SmsManager MySmsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    ArrayList<String> msgArray = MySmsManager.divideMessage(DefaultMsgTemplate);
    MySmsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(SendSMSTo, null,msgArray, null, null);
    CurrentSmsParts = msgArray.size();

    Log.d("SMS DETAILS : ", "\nFOUND BELOW LOLLIPOP MR1...");
    Log.d("SMS DETAILS : ", "\nDETECTED DEFAULT SMS SIM WHICHEVER AVAILABLE...");
    Log.d("SMS DETAILS : ", "\nSENT MSG USING SIM1 OR SIM2 WHICHEVER IS AVAILABLE...");
}


ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("address", SendSMSTo);
values.put("body", DefaultMsgTemplate);
getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);

SMSDone++;
```

Here `SMSDone` is my `counter` to count the `today sent SMSs` via my application... ; `But Users are also able to send SMSs, without my application..!!`

> So..,
>
> 1. How can i query SMS uri to get todays sent SMS number for both of the SIM cards / Numbers?
> 2. I am inserting my SMS in Sent SMS; But how to also insert SIM number via which it has been sent, from my application?

Comment: What do you mean by "today"? The past 24 hours? Or since midnight? As for the SIM card number, it's stored in the `Telephony.Sms.SUBSCRIPTION_ID` (`"sub_id"`) column.

Comment: @MikeM. I mean since midnight. In other words for todays date only. Like $For today 4 SMSs sent from SIM1 & & SMSs sent from SIM2 via Uri query

Comment: OK, I assume you know how to `query()`, since you know how to `insert()`, yeah? The message time is stored in the `"date"` column, in epoch milliseconds. Simple example: get a `Calendar` instance – which will be automatically set to the current date/time – then `set()` the `HOUR_OF_DAY`, `MINUTE`, `SECOND`, and `MILLISECOND` to `0`. Then do a query with a _where_ clause of `date + " > " + cal.getTimeInMillis()`. Got it? You can then determine which messages are from which SIM by the `"sub_id"` column. You could also integrate that column into the query, if you want them in separate batches.

Comment: @MikeM., Yes I have queried contact uri and sms but i am not so fluent in that; I have also set time in calendar instance with the HH, MM, SS for setting Alarms and in Other cases. I am getting the idea but i insist and request to answer this question with same code ; so that i can accept it as answer and also it would be helpful to others whoever will search for this in future...

Comment: @MikeM., Yes .., It is done. You can have a look on my implementation and let me know is it perfect. I appreciate your help..., Up voted and credit given to you. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, looks OK to me. You don't really have to set the `Calendar`'s `YEAR`, `MONTH`, and `DAY_OF_MONTH`, though. It's kind of redundant. Just FYI. Cheers!

Comment: @MikeM., Yes.. it would redundant of course. HOUR_OF_DAY, MINUTE, SECOND to 0 only..!! Thanks a lot. Have the good times in coding..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits : Mike M

Followed his instructions and by having basics of earlier uri querying this is the final answer i have implemented....

```
Log.d("Executing :", "from here....\n");

try 
{
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
c1.setTime(new Date());

Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
c2.set(Calendar.YEAR, c1.get(Calendar.YEAR));
c2.set(Calendar.MONTH, c1.get(Calendar.MONTH));
c2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
c2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
c2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
c2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

long TodayStartedAt = c2.getTimeInMillis();

Log.d("Today started at ", "here" + TodayStartedAt);

final Uri SMS_INBOX = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(SMS_INBOX, null, "date>=" + TodayStartedAt, null, null);
List < String > items = new ArrayList < String > ();

int counter = 0;

while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
{
    String Date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date"));
    String SmsBody = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"));
    String PhoneNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address"));
    String FromSIM = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("sub_id"));

    Log.d("Counter : ", counter + "\n");

    Log.d("Date : ", Date + "\n");
    Log.d("PhoneNumber : ", PhoneNumber + "\n");
    Log.d("FromSIM : ", FromSIM + "\n");
    Log.d("SmsBody : ", SmsBody + "\n");

    counter++;
}
cursor.close();
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
Log.e("exception :", "is", e);
}
```

Thanks @Mike M. And Posted as it may help others in future...